# How to offset carriage in $write function in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to print using a built-in *$write()* function in verilog vcs on the same line twice, where the second write starts at a specified character position beginning from the column 0. Is it even possible? The pseudo-code would be something like:

```
$write("Hello world");       // Assuming printed from a new line
$write("Test",10);           // Starts printing on the same line at 10th position from the beginning
```

The output console would look like:

```
Hello worlTest
```

Comment: sorry, but it looks like you have not tried anything yet. Try it first.

Comment: you cannot do it in any language with any print statement. you can move cartridge to the beginning of line and completely override the string or supply particular terminal sequences to move the cursor. Your best bet is to prepare the string in the form you want it and $write it once.

Comment: Question was clear as a *bell character* to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the proper ASCII escape sequences for the terminal the output is going to. And not all terminal windows support the same codes or this feature at all. For example see the [Move Cursor commands](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) for the vt-100.

Other than that, you can manipulate a string before printing it.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I used _$write("%c[100D",27,"%c[10C",27);_ to first move cursor to the left (very beginning), and then 10 spaces to the right.